# how to check that click event done by mouse Scroll click while form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my simple form, **js_submit_loading** is assigned to `<form>`
and **btn-loading** is assigned to SEND `<button>`

Here is my js code:

```
    $('.js_submit_loading').on('submit',function (){
        $(this).find('#btn-loading').button('loading');
    });
```

Now, how can i detect that button was clicked by **left mouse button** or **scroll button** i only know that which==2 stands for scroll click.

thanks in adv. for help

Comment: @Pete that question is regarding HTML button... my question is regarding Mouse button :)

Answer (score 1):

event.which will give 1, 2 or 3 for left, middle and right mouse buttons respectively.

```
$( "#whichkey" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
});
```

or

```
$('#submit').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Comment: but how to check value ON SUBMIT event?